# Cannot Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite for .net Core (Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 3.1.6 is not compatible)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

When trying to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite NuGet package(Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.5), it shows

> Error NU1202  Package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 3.1.6 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 3.1.6 does not support any target frameworks.

tried with net5.0 same issue

> Error NU1202  Package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 3.1.6 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 3.1.6 does not support any target frameworks.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure but have you tried it on .NET Core 2.0, this package has dependency on Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions which supports ".NETStandard 2.0" means .NET CORE 2.0

Comment: Did you perform a clean build?

Comment: @jdweng yes, no luck

Comment: @AribYousuf Too old right?

Comment: Do you have .NET Core 3.1 SDK/runtime installed? `dotnet --list-sdks` & `dotnet --list-runtimes` ?  Also try updating them if you have any of the older ones

Comment: @Krish Yes, seen it on the NuGet website.

Comment: @Tseng Ok, let me try that